# Python Azure webjob passing parameters

Tags: python, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a Python WebJob living in Azure and I'm trying to pass parameters to it.

I've found documentation saying that I should be able to post the URL and add:`?arguments={'arg1', 'arg2'}` after it.

However, when I do that and then try to `print(sys.argv)` in my code, it's only printing the name of the Python file and none of the arguments I pass to it.

How do I get the arguments to pass to my Python code? I am also using a run.cmd in my Azure directory to trigger my Python code if that makes a difference.

UPDATE: So I tested it in another script without the run.cmd and that certainly is the problem. If I just do `?arguments=22 66` it works. So how do I pass parameters when I'm using a run.cmd file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: in the run.cmd file, you need to put "%*" after your script name and it will detect any arguments you passed in the URL.

Comment: have you been able to put a pandas webjob and if you have are you able to share how you did it? Happy for you to chat. Ready to give my email address. I have tried severally and the job is urgent. Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking to pass named parameter, then add it in the url like:

```
url?arguments=--arg1 val1 --arg2 "val2" --arg3 0.99
```